# tidying the rooms, or tidying their rooms?

Tags: articles

Which answer should I choose?

> These could be taking out the rubbish, emptying the dishwasher, walking the dog, vacuuming the carpets or tidying ______ rooms.

A. the
B. a
C. their
D. theirs

Is C is better than A?

**EDIT**:

The full context is:

> Read the text below and choose the correct word for each space:
>
> Many children in the UK ( get ) pocket money. In the USA it's called an allowance but it's ( the ) same thing. Often children ( do ) small jobs for their pocket money. These could be taking out the rubbish, emptying the dishwasher, walking the dog, vacuuming the carpets or tidying (        ) rooms.

Comment: These could be taking out the rubbish, emptying the dishwasher, walking the dog, vacuuming the carpets or tidying (          ) rooms.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! In future questions, I hope you'll provide [more context about where the question came from](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source), along with [more details](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) about your research. (Those two links provide some additional information than is too lengthy to leave in a comment.)

Comment: I'd go for *'the.'* Why? Because the *flow* is like that... everywhere, it's the definite article used, so why use the pronoun in the last?

Answer (score 1):

As you figured out, B can't be correct. We don't use the indefinite article with a plural noun, and the phrase "tidying a rooms" is ungrammatical.

As for choosing between A and C, that's a bit of a challenge, because you've given us no context. Is this a sentence you are writing as part of an essay? An exercise problem on a worksheet? Something you found in a magazine?

I'll assume it's an exercise from a workbook, and I'll make a case for either answer.

Let's say I'm placing a want ad for a maid to work at my house. In that case, I might say something like:

> You'll be expected to arrive before 10AM each day. Your duties will vary from day to day, but they could be taking out the rubbish, emptying the dishwasher, walking the dog, vacuuming the carpets or tidying the rooms.

Now let's pretend that I am giving advice for chores that parents might give to children, teaching them to become more responsible. In that case, I might say:

> Most chores take less than half an hour to complete. These could be taking out the rubbish, emptying the dishwasher, walking the dog, vacuuming the carpets or tidying their rooms.

The word *their* works in this case, because I'm talking about how each child would tidy up his or her own bedroom. The rubbish, the dishwasher, the dog, and the carpets all belong to the household at large, but the room to be tidied "belongs" to the child, so we can shift the determiner from "the" to "their".

I suspect this is the small nuance that the workbook was trying to get learners to understand, but sometimes people who write such learning materials provide options that are not necessarily ungrammatical, leaving native speakers scratching their heads in confusion.

Interestingly enough, though, if I were actually writing that ad for the maid, there is a good chance I would use no article at all:

> You'll be expected to arrive before 10AM each day. Your duties will vary from day to day, but they could include taking out the rubbish, emptying the dishwasher, walking the dog, vacuuming carpets, or tidying rooms.

Comment: Thank you very much ,there is more information :

Read the text below and choose the crooect word for each space .


Many children in the UK ( get ) pocket money . In the USA it's called an allowance but it's ( the ) same thing .Often children ( do ) small jobs for their pocket money . These could be taking out the rubbish, emptying the dishwasher, walking the dog, vacuuming the carpets or tidying (     ) rooms.

Comment: Well, there you go; _their_ it is.

Comment: Agree with the explanation and answer. “Their rooms” in this context.